# Solving repeating cells in tableView

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a bunch of posts that are loaded into a tableview that my users should be able to either upvote/downvote.  Similar to the app "Yik-yak".  There should also be a label that keeps track of the current votes.

Problem:  When the user scrolls around and upvotes, sometimes the label gets updated on the wrong labels (nearby labels are voted up even when they weren't tapped).  However, my firebase database is correct.   I've also tried other methods on other posts: i.e. prepareForReuse but it doesn't seem to be working.

Code for PostCell/Prepare for reuse:

```
class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var eventCountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var upvoteButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var downvotebutton: UIButton!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        eventCountLabel.text = String(counter)

    }
```

Code for cell (I think the error might be how I'm reading it? Thoughts?)

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell
      let event: EventModel

      event = eventList[indexPath.row]

      let count = Database.database().reference().child(event.id!).child("counter")

            count.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                cell.eventCountLabel.text = "\(snapshot.value!)"
            })
}
```

Code for adding +1 when button is clicked

```
    @objc func upvoteClicked(sender:UIButton) {
        let buttonRow = sender.tag
        let event: EventModel
        event = eventList[buttonRow]

        ref.child(event.id!).child("tracker").setValue(event.tracker! - 1)
        let upvoteCount = ref.child(event.id!).child("counter")

        upvoteCount.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let counted = snapshot.value as? Int
            self.ref.child(event.id!).child("counter").setValue(counted! + 1)
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you retrieve the counter value in `cellForRow` from the database asynchronouly. This is a very bad practice.

In `cellForRow` just set the counter value from the `EventModel`, you might add an appropriate property (for example `counter`)

```
let event = eventList[indexPath.row]
cell.eventCountLabel.text = String(event.counter)
```

```
  let count = Database.database().reference().child(event.id!).child("counter")

   count.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
      cell.eventCountLabel.text = "\(snapshot.value!)"
   })
```

In `upvoteClicked` update the model after updating the database and then reload the row

```
@objc func upvoteClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    let buttonRow = sender.tag
    let event = eventList[buttonRow]

    ref.child(event.id!).child("tracker").setValue(event.tracker! - 1)
    let upvoteCount = ref.child(event.id!).child("counter")

    upvoteCount.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let counted = snapshot.value as? Int
        self.ref.child(event.id!).child("counter").setValue(counted! + 1)
        event.counter = counted + 1
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: buttonRow, section: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath],  with:. automatic)
    })

}
```

The method `prepareForReuse` in the cell is not needed. Delete it.